# How to check if ID is valid during parsing - ParseTreeListener enter event not called

Tags: antlr4

My grammar contains the following:

```
assignment
: ID ASSIGN expr
;

expr
 : MINUS expr                 #unaryMinusExpr
 | NOT expr                   #notExpr
 | expr MULT expr             #multExpr
 | expr DIV expr              #divExpr
 | expr PLUS expr             #plusExpr
 | expr MINUS expr            #minusExpr
 | expr LTEQ expr             #lteqExpr
 | expr GTEQ expr             #gteqExpr
 | expr LT expr               #ltExpr
 | expr GT expr               #gtExpr
 | expr NEQ expr              #neqExpr
 | expr EQ expr               #eqExpr
 | expr AND expr              #andExpr
 | expr OR expr               #orExpr
 | atom                       #atomExpr
 ;

atom
 : OPAR expr CPAR #parExpr
 | (INT | FLOAT)  #numberAtom
 | (TRUE | FALSE) #booleanAtom
 | STRING         #stringAtom
 | ID             #idAtom
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;
```

The ID here represents an entry (row) in a database which the user refers to by, well :), the ID. So when parsing the formula, I'd like to check that they entered a valid ID.

From what I can tell, the way to go is to have a ParseTreeListener that overrides EnterIdAtom so I can throw an RecognitionException. So I hooked that up, but the Enter event is never called.

```
class MyListener : BaseListener
{
     public override EnterIdAtom(IdAtomContext context)
     {
          if (!CheckForValidId(context.ID().GetText())
          {
               throw new RecognitionException(...)
          }
     }
}
```

Not sure why?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post some code for your `ParseTreeListener`? Although I'd prefer a parse tree walker if the changes can be made after parsing... You might also check lexer actions (https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules). This will allow the lexer to check the ID's at lexing time, although  I'd not do this.

Comment: Added sample code. If there was a way to simply get a list after the lexer is done, that would work as well. Something like lexer.GetListOfIdAtoms()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using [`Parser.addParseListener`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.html#addParseListener(org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeListener)) (bold font added by me):

> Registers listener to receive events during the parsing process.
>
> To support output-preserving grammar transformations (including but not limited to left-recursion removal, automated left-factoring, and optimized code generation), calls to listener methods during the parse may differ substantially from calls made by `ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT` used after the parse is complete. In particular, rule entry and exit events may occur in a different order during the parse than after the parser. **In addition, calls to certain rule entry methods may be omitted.**
>
> With the following specific exceptions, calls to listener events are *deterministic*, i.e. for identical input the calls to listener methods will be the same.
>
> - Alterations to the grammar used to generate code may change the behavior of the listener calls.
> - Alterations to the command line options passed to ANTLR 4 when generating the parser may change the behavior of the listener calls.
> - Changing the version of the ANTLR Tool used to generate the parser may change the behavior of the listener calls.

If this is the case, you should be using `ParseTreeWalker` to walk the tree after parsing is complete, instead of trying to mix the two operations together.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes sense. A quick related question. Is there an easy way to get a list of IDs from either the parser, tree, or walker? While I can keep track of them in my listener, I thought I'd check if there is already a built-in way of doing that?

Comment: Found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769343/antlr4-flattening-a-parserrulecontext-tree-into-an-array/22770561#22770561

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a breakpoint at:

```
public override void enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx)
```

or

```
public override void enterAtom(AtomContext ctx)
```

This should give you a clue if the rule is even invoked.

Otherwise try this:

```
atom
 : OPAR expr CPAR #parExpr
 | (INT | FLOAT)  #numberAtom
 | (TRUE | FALSE) #booleanAtom
 | STRING         #stringAtom
 | atomId            // changed!
 ;


atomId
 :  ID
 ;
```

This will generate a new "real" context, which you can visit:

```
public override void enterAtom(AtomIdContext ctx) {}
```